# android - Как сделать круглый ProgressBar?

Tags: android, progress-bar

Всем добрый вечер. Как сделать круглый `ProgressBar` с принципом работы горизонтального? Мне нужно его сделать вокруг `FloatingActionButton`. Тоесть, нажимаешь на `FAB` и вокруг него начинает действовать `ProgressBar`. Когда он пройдет круг, он должен исчезнуть. Но меня интересует лишь `xml`. Как вообще сделать его круглым?

Comment: полностью в xml не получится, ибо вам придется привязываться к подгружаемым данным, и как минимум строчка кода будет. В xml вы можете нарисовать этот progressbar, потом привязать к View, вы можете сделать Анимацию и даже привязать её к нужному типу данных, но эти данные скорей всего будут испускаться динамически в коде. Более того, если делать его поверх FAB, нужно ещё подкрутить его, под него, что ещё усложняет задачу.

Comment: почему бы не применить что-то готовое? например, https://github.com/ckurtm/FabButton

Comment: @Fitz, нашел на английском форуме